# header specific meta box result detect url

Tags: metabox, custom-header

I've got 3 header.php files and 1 detects whether their either on page 1 or page 2. I have a custom meta box thats outputting the results onto each header - that all works fine.

However when I go a page deeper the meta box information isn't showing, I've tried various if statements but nothing shows up.

Any help would be great.

my header output looks like:

```
<?php
global $post;
$header_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page-header-meta', true);
if( isset( $header_meta ) ) {
echo '<h1>' . $header_meta . '</h1>';
}
else {
    echo '<h1>Knowledgebase</h1>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global $post;
$header_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page-header-meta', true);
if( isset( $header_meta ) ) {
echo '<h1>' . $header_meta . '</h1>';
}
else {
    echo '<h1>Knowledgebase</h1>';
}
```

What this portion of code does is it checks the 'page-header-meta' value according to the page being displayed. IF your parent page has the metavalue set then the header will display. Similarly for the child pages also you need to set the meta value to display the particular header.

Comment: how do i set it for child pages?

Comment: don't you have the same metabox in the "Add New" child page ??

Comment: not sure what you mean by "Add New"?

Comment: How are you adding the child pages?

Comment: inside the admin panel - think I've managed to solve it via the get_queried_object(); thanks!